# xmppstream delegate methods not getting called on my custom class

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xmppframework

I started with xmppframework recently,but i am stuck with an issue.i am able to connect to my server on my local network but the xmppstreamdelegate methods are  not getting called on my custom class,but works absolutely fine on appdelegate class .Can anyone pls help me on this.Is the delegate only supported on the appdelegate class ?

Header:

```
@interface XmppClass : NSObject<XMPPStreamDelegate>{
    XMPPStream *xmppStream;
    Login * loginDetail;
    BOOL allowSelfSignedCertificates;
    BOOL allowSSLHostNameMismatch;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) XMPPStream *xmppStream;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Login *loginDetail;
- (id)initWithLogin:(Login *) loginrefernce;
- (BOOL)connect;
- (void)disconnect;
- (void)setupStream;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation XmppClass

@synthesize xmppStream;
@synthesize loginDetail;
- (id)initWithLogin:(Login *) loginrefernce
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.loginDetail=loginrefernce;
        [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
        [self setupStream];
        [self connect];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setupStream
{
NSAssert(xmppStream == nil, @"Method setupStream invoked multiple times");
// Setup xmpp stream
// 
// The XMPPStream is the base class for all activity.
// Everything else plugs into the xmppStream, such as modules/extensions and delegates.

xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
{
// Want xmpp to run in the background?
// 
// P.S. - The simulator doesn't support backgrounding yet.
//        When you try to set the associated property on the simulator, it simply fails.
//        And when you background an app on the simulator,
//        it just queues network traffic til the app is foregrounded again.
//        We are patiently waiting for a fix from Apple.
//        If you do enableBackgroundingOnSocket on the simulator,
//        you will simply see an error message from the xmpp stack when it fails to set the property.
xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES;
}
#endif

NSLog(@"setup stream");
[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppStream setHostName:@"10.68.202.123"];
//[xmppStream setHostPort:8070];

allowSelfSignedCertificates = NO;
allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;

// You may need to alter these settings depending on the server you're connecting to

}

- (BOOL)connect
{
    NSLog(@"connect");
    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }


//
// If you don't want to use the Settings view to set the JID, 
// uncomment the section below to hard code a JID and password.
// 
// myJID = @"user@gmail.com/xmppframework";
// myPassword = @"";
if (self.loginDetail.emailId == nil || self.loginDetail.password == nil) {
    return NO;
}

[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[self.loginDetail.emailId      stringByAppendingString:@"/pc"]]];


NSError *error = nil;
if (![xmppStream connect:&error])
{

    NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);

    return NO;
}

return YES;
}

- (void)disconnect
{
    [xmppStream disconnect];
}
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketDidConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket 
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    NSLog(@"some security thing");
    if (allowSelfSignedCertificates)
    {
        [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString  *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
    }
    if (allowSSLHostNameMismatch)
    {
        [settings setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
    }
    else
   {
        // Google does things incorrectly (does not conform to RFC).
        // Because so many people ask questions about this (assume xmpp framework is broken),
        // I've explicitly added code that shows how other xmpp clients "do the right thing"
        // when connecting to a google server (gmail, or google apps for domains).
        NSString *expectedCertName = nil;
        NSString *serverDomain = xmppStream.hostName;
        NSString *virtualDomain = [xmppStream.myJID domain];
        if ([serverDomain isEqualToString:@"talk.google.com"])
        {
             if ([virtualDomain isEqualToString:@"gmail.com"])
             {
                  expectedCertName = virtualDomain;
             }
             else
             {
                  expectedCertName = serverDomain;
             }
        }
        else if (serverDomain == nil)
        {
             expectedCertName = virtualDomain;
        }
        else
        {
             expectedCertName = serverDomain;
        }
        if (expectedCertName)
        {
             [settings setObject:expectedCertName forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
        }
}
```

}

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidSecure:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    NSLog(@"connected");
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:self.loginDetail.password error:&error])
    {
            DDLogError(@"Error authenticating: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    NSLog(@"authenticated");

}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    NSLog(@"did not authenticate");
}

- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    return NO;
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    // A simple example of inbound message handling.

}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [presence fromStr]);
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveError:(id)error
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
@end
```

Comment: Would you please indent your code?

Comment: Is `-setupStream` called on your instance of XmppClass? And `-connect`? Does `[xmppStream connect]` return YES? Are you using ARC? What's the output? What's the code which creates your instance of XmppClass?

Comment: You can use any class as your XMPPStreamDelegate.

Comment: @noa -setupStream and -connect are called from - (id)initWithLogin:(Login *) loginrefernce and that intuen is called on instance of xmpp class as : XmppClass * xmppRef=[[XmppClass alloc] initWithLogin:self];

Comment: And ya using ARC , and the connect method returns YES and i am connected according to LOGS  on the XMPPStream methods,but the corresponding delegate methods on XmppClass are not getting called.

Comment: I have one more issue that i am stuck with regarding xmppframework , it appears to be a parser issue,while running the sample project of XMPPFramework i got this issue,would be glad if you could help me with this : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355228/connection-disconnects-with-error-internal-error-code-1-errordomain-libxmlerro

Comment: I saw that question and sorry, but I've no idea. What does your main look like? Does your application have a working run loop? Also have you tried stepping through -connect to make sure it's proceeding as you expect? Have you tried removing that isDisconnected check?

Comment: I have the same problem, works fine in appdelegate but if i put it in a custom class delegates wont be fired and nothing gets logged. did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the problem is that your class instance, that is a delegate for your XMPPStream is released before the delegate method is called on it. Make it more persistent by making this class a property or instance variable of other class or by using dispatch_once. For example,

Change

```
YourClass *instance = [[YourClass alloc] init];
instance.xmppStream = ....
```

by

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) YourClass *instance;
self.instance = [[YourClass alloc] init];
self.instance.xmppStream = ....
```

Here YourClass contains XMPPStream and is delegate for it.

I've written a big blog post on this problem. This is pretty common situation.
http://blog.alwawee.com/2013/07/31/on-xmppframework-delegate-method-not-being-called/

Comment: I am having the same problem. Your blog post has gone missing, can I find it somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: http://blog.alwawee.com/2013/07/31/on-xmppframework-delegate-method-not-being-called/ - here it is

Answer (score 0):

you can use the multicast,sth like this

```
[[self appDelegate].xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem... this helped me. Hope it works for you, just make following Changes in your code.

```
Static XmppClass *selfRef = nil;
@implementation XmppClass
@synthesize xmppStream;
- (void)setupStream
{
// Setup xmpp stream
selfRef = [[XmppClass alloc] init];
xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[xmppStream addDelegate:selfRef delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```